# python regex - finding phone number

Tags: python, regex

I've tried the following code:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'''(\+)*\d*                 # optional + sign for international calls
                   ([" "-\)]{,1}\d+)*    # main chain of numbers, numbers separated by a space, ) or a hyphen
                   ''',re.VERBOSE)
print(r.findall('+00 0000 0000 is my number and +44-787-77950 was my uk number'))
```

The expected result

```
[('+00',' 0000',' 0000'),('+44','-787','-77950')]
```

Or, better:

```
['+00 0000 0000','+44-787-77950']
```

But the life isn't so easy, instead I get a cryptic

```
[('+', ' 0000'), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('+', '44'), ('', ''), ('', '787'), ('', ''), ('', '77950'), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', '')]
```

Why does it behave weirdly and how would I fix it?

Edit - my example was not the best one, the I wanted '+somenumber' to be optional - not all the phone numbers sent to me are international ones and thus does not have to include + sign

I'm sorry for not making this clear.

So far the closest thing to what I want seems to be

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'''(\+)?(\d+)                 # optional + sign for international calls
                   ([" "-\)]{,1}\d+)+    # main chain of numbers, numbers separated by a space, ) or a hyphen
                   ''',re.VERBOSE)
print(r.findall('+00 0000 0000 is my number and +44-787-77950 was my uk number'))
```

which gives

```
[('+', '00', ' 0000'), ('+', '4', '4'), ('', '78', '7'), ('', '7795', '0')]
```

Comment: `)*` => `)+` for starters. Matching 0 times matches empty string.

Comment: Probably just [`\+?\d+(?:[- \)]+\d+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/0qqKYh/1) will do. Actually, you should decide what should be obligatory in the pattern and what should not.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew \+?\d+(?:[- `\)`]+\d+)+ what does this part mean?

Comment: @Vinny There is a link to regex101 in my comment, there is the explanation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, you save my day

Comment: Please edit the expected results in the question, then I'll be able to post the answer. You seem to want `['+00 0000 0000','+44-787-77950']`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You could just answer, your results works better than what's expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix for you pattern is

```
\+?\d+(?:[- \)]+\d+)+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0qqKYh/1). Note that use of the non-capturing group that helps avoid creating lists of tuples in the result of the `re.findall` call.

**Details**

- `\+?` - an optional (1 or 0) plus signs
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[- )]+` - 1 or more `-`, `spaces,`)` chars
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `)+` - 1 or more repetitions (the whole `(?:...)` sequence of patterns are quantified this way, both symbols and digits are required at least once and as a sequence).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/McZEjm):

```
import re
rx = r"\+?\d+(?:[- )]+\d+)+"
s = "+00 0000 0000 is my number and +44-787-77950 was my uk number"
print(re.findall(rx, s))
# => ['+00 0000 0000', '+44-787-77950']
```

Answer (score 0):

All your tokens are optional, so the regex can and will match the empty string.

I think you will want to use the following :

```
(\+)?(\d+)([ \-)]?\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to capture phone numbers, it will skip the spaces or dashes and keep just the number itself:

```
s = '+00 0000 0000 is my number and +44-787-77950 was my uk number'   
p = '(\+\d+)(?:[\s-])(\d+)(?:[\s-])(\d+)'

re.findall(p, s)
[('+00', '0000', '0000'), ('+44', '787', '77950')]
```

The pattern means:

- `(\+\d+)` - look for + followed by one or more digits
- `(?:[\s-])` - followed by a space or a dash, in a non-capturing group (means it 
  needs to be there, but don't return in the matched object)
- `(\d+)` - another one or more digits

Then you can easily construct the phone numbers with space / dashes with `join`.

```
for number in re.findall(p, s):
    print '-'.join(number)

+00-0000-0000
+44-787-77950
```